# How to fix sharp edge in 3d mesh object

Tags: mesh, 3d-printing

[image]

I'm just trying to add numbers on to a basic shape. Most of my numbers turned out fine except my #3 which has this sharp edge on the right side. Is this a basic fix? I'd really like some help to know how to fix in the future.
Much thanks!

Comment: hello, please share your object: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Is this is a project I intend to sell, do I still keep it's rights if I place it?

Comment: if you share something there's always the risk that someone steals it, so only share the bare minimum, if you can't, show more pictures so that we try to understand, for example show pictures of your topology

Comment: Sounds good, I uploaded just the number i'm having a problem with does this text help?[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=Z0g8kjen" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/Z0g8kjen/)

Comment: so I guess you've just converted a curve to mesh? There must have been an extra vertex in the curve and it has created this protrusion, switch to X ray mode with alt Z, go in ortho top view with 5 and 7, select this part with the lasso, delete with X, then select the missing face with edge loop select and fill with F